# Is Time Stretching the same as Time Remapping?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a 1400 frame animation at 30 fps and I want to change it to 60 fps while maintaining the relative placement of keyframes. I found a 2021 video that shows how to use the **Time Remapping** options in the Output Properties, but when I look in my Blender version I see instead **Time Stretching.** Are they the same thing? By the way, changing values in Time Stretching doesn't appear to accomplish the same thing as that demonstrated with Time Remapping in the video. Thanks. Blender 3.10, Windows 11

Comment: It's the same, different name

Answer (score 2):

It's like a Speed/Duration thing yes. Doesn't allow for the granularity you get in Time Remapping, just stretches your keys out. Set your time stretch to 200 and you'll have the desired 30 to 60fps result.

Alternatively you can find a way to select all the keys in your scene, take your playhead to the start of your animation and then scale it up by 2x ( <kbd>S</kbd>,  <kbd>2</kbd>,  <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and then change your render settings to 60fps.